# Displaying SQL select result on JAVA

Tags: java, sql

How do I display SQL result with system print?

Here are my code

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oopdb","root","12345");
    st = con.createStatement();

    //set query
    String s = "SELECT Category FROM infocollected WHERE Adminno='123'";

    //save query result into rs
    rs = st.executeQuery(s);

    //retrieve category from result
    String category = rs.getString("Category");

    //print out result to console
    System.out.println("category");
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `rs.next()` before using the results?

Comment: Don't write "solved" into the title. Either accept the correct answer or write an answer yourself if none of them are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (rs.next()) {
String category = rs.getString("Category");
System.out.println(category);
}
```

And check if your DB is not Empty

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't surround variables with double quotes. And also take a loot at @Gatusko's answer.

Replace it with:

```
// ...

//retrieve category from result
String category = rs.getString("Category");

//print out result to console
System.out.println(category);
```

Comment: thanks bro, a careless mistake. still not working thou :(

Answer (score -1):

When you want to print a variable, there is no need to indicate it with `""` . Just only the variable name.

- For example if you use your code, your console is showing: category
- However if you use `System.out.println(category);` your console will print the value of the variable.